# Loop function for several regressions

Tags: r

I was wondering how I can have a loop function (or any function in plyr package) to calculate the regression line between `x` and each of `y1,y2,y3` separately and bring all the results into a new data.frame. 2.How can I have a plot of x and each of these `y (y1,y2,y3)`

```
subject<-seq(1,21,1)
x<-seq(10,30,1)
y1<-seq(15,35,1)
y2<-seq(20,40,1)
y3<-seq(50,70,1)
a<-data.frame(subject,x,y1,y2,y3)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure exactly which results you want to have in the end. Now I am just saving the intercept and slope.

```
results <- data.frame()
for (i in colnames(a)[! colnames(a) %in% c('subject','x')]) {
results <- rbind(results,coefficients(lm(x ~ get(i), a)))
}
colnames(results) <- c('intercept','slope')
results
```

Note: In R the intercept is somehow not what you would normally think the intercept is. Normally, the intercept is the y where x=0. In R it's the x where y=0.

For the plot you first need to figure out the maximum and minimum of the y's in order to set the plot area.

```
min_y <- min(a$y1,a$y2,a$y3)
max_y <- max(a$y1,a$y2,a$y3)

plot(x, y1, ylim = c(min_y, max_y))
points(x, y2, yaxt = 'n', ylab = '')
points(x, y3, yaxt = 'n', ylab = '')
```

See [image]

Comment: Thanks for your help. In my real data set, I have different variable, so I can not use for (i in colnames(a)[! colnames(a) %in% c('subject','x')]). Do you have any suggestion?

Comment: Hi Sarah, just replace the vector `c('subject','x')` in `for (i in colnames(a)[! colnames(a) %in% c('subject','x')])` with the column names that you do not want to include in the regression/the columns that are not supposed to be independent variables in your regression. So for example if you have an additional column called 'year' that is not a regressor, do `c('subject','x','year')`.

Comment: @ guscht, Hi, thanks for your reply. I have around 100 variables in the data set and it is not possible to mention their names. Also, I have, yi, i=1 to 15 in the model.

Comment: You could try to select all columns that start with a y: `colnames(a)[substring(colnames(a),1,1) == "y"]`. So then it would be: `for (i in colnames(a)[substring(colnames(a),1,1) == "y"])`